# Binding BorderBackground in ListboxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I tried different ways to solve the Problem. First I bound in my ViewModel the MainColor as String,Color,Brush and tried to bind it to the Border -> don't worked for me. Second was an Converter, but I couldn't bind correct the string to activate the converter. The only thing that worked with the Bind the MainColor as string to a Label style, that I have also in the same Resource. So now the change in the Label works, but not in the Listbox.

**My View:**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/ResourcePageCuttingData.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Material}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMat, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource styleMat}"   Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,0"></ListBox>
<Label Style="{StaticResource Label_Search}"  Content="{DynamicResource so_lbl_cm}" ></Label>
```

**My Listbox in ResourceDictonary:**

```
<Style x:Key="styleMat" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=styleLocMschItem}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ResultMatDataTemplate}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <Border BorderBrush="#5A5A5A" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4">
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="1">
                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="1"></ItemsPresenter>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ResultMatDataTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                   FontSize="20"
               ></TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>

<Style  x:Key="styleLocMachItem" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Grid x:Name="grid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border x:Name="hover"
                        Background="YellowGreen"
                        Visibility="Collapsed">
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="orginal"
                        Background="{Binding MainColor}">
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="highlight"
                            Property="Visibility"
                            Value="Visible">
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The MainColor is not working in Border x:Name="original"

**My Label:**

```
<Style x:Key="Label_Search" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding MainColor}" />
</Style>
```

Here the MainColor works fine

**My ViewModel:**

```
public CuttingSpeed_ViewModel()
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case "Fast":
                MainColor = "Pink";
                    break;        
             case "Slow":
                MainColor = "Yellow";
                    break;
            default:
                   MainColor ="Red";
                 break;
        }}
    private string _MainColor;

    public string MainColor
    {
        get { return _MainColor; }
        set { _MainColor = value; OnPropertyChanged("MainColor"); }
    }
    public IEnumerable<string> Material
    {
        get { return _Material; }
        set { _Material = value; OnPropertyChanged("Material"); }
    }
    private string _SelectedMat;

    public string SelectedMat
    {
        get { return _SelectedMat; }

        set
        {..}}
```

I think there should be something in xaml that don't allow me to get the value MainColor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MainColor` property should return a `Brush`:

```
public CuttingSpeed_ViewModel()
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case "Fast":
            MainColor = Brushes.Pink;
            break;
        case "Slow":
            MainColor = Brushes.Yellow;
            break;
        default:
            MainColor = Brushes.Red;
            break;
    }
}

private Brush _MainColor;
public Brush MainColor
{
    get { return _MainColor; }
    set { _MainColor = value; OnPropertyChanged("MainColor"); }
}
```

You should also bind to the `DataContext` of the parent `ListBox`:

```
<Border x:Name="orginal" Background="{Binding DataContext.MainColor, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}">
```